# Count rows according criterias

Tags: excel, count

I want to count the number of items i have in my stock at each time of the day. 
Basically, I have an "enter date" and an "exit date".

In the last month I want to count how many items were in my stock.

For example, on date = July 15 at 06.00 AM, 
I need that : `enter_date <= date` and `date >= exit_date`.

I am struggling to find an Excel function that can do that for me..
I tried `COUNTIFS` but it is not working . if someone has an idea?

I did `=COUNTIFS(enter,"<=" F4, exit, ">=" F4)` 
but the issue here is that `enter<=F4` is `false` because not all of my rows have enter `<=F4`

How can I tell Excel,

> "Go through the row, verify the condition and increment by one if its
>   verified."

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: hey Adi, wasnt precise enough i want to go through all the rows in my column and I dont know how to do loops in Excel..

Comment: Sorry Hannah, I didn't know you wanted to loop through the rows. As far as I know (I researched this a bit on Google/SO), it's impossible to loop through rows without Excel VBA :-(    But, you could copy/paste the formula on every row for all of the rows, and then get the sum of those values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEVALUE()`

```
= COUNTIFS(your_range, DATEVALUE(enter_date) <= DATEVALUE(date), your_range,  DATEVALUE(date) >= DATEVALUE(exit_date))
```

your_range --> the range you're applying your criteria to (in this case, the row)

enter_date --> your entry date

exit_date  --> your exit date

date       --> your date (replace `date` with `TODAY()` if you want the current date)

Based on your last sentence, this should work! ;-)